# Getting Error Unable to evaluate expression in Azure Web Application Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Application. I am getting an error constantly as:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack

for the code:

```
    if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
```

I tried looking different solutions but didn't work.
Kindly Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're trying to rewrite a request from http to https. If so, that is not the optimal way to do it. [Try rewrite rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/01/07/https-only-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) in your web.config instead.